# Automatically getting Mojang bearer token

Tags: python, api, python-requests, minecraft, bearer-token

I am writing a program that can change your Mojang username at whatever time you specify (i.e. the name "tom" becomes available at 09:05:39 so you would set the program to change your name to "tom" at that time). To do this you need a bearer token. I can log into minecraft.net and use EditThisCookie to access that, but I want to be able to have the program wait until it is within a minute of the name dropping to gather proxies and the bearer token automatically for situations where a name is becoming available in the middle of the night or I'm just lazy. I'm not sure why my function for getting the bearer token won't work. I referenced [this](https://wiki.vg/Authentication) to write this code.

```py
    def getAT():
        jsonForAT = json.dumps({"agent":{"name":"Minecraft","version":1},"username":email,"password":password,"clientToken":""})
        headersForAT = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        requestForAT = requests.post('https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate', data=jsonForAT, headers=headersForAT)
    
        pullATRequestData = requestForAT.json()
        AT = pullATRequestData["accessToken"]
        return AT
```

I am really confused since when I use this, I get a 401 error but the program works when I get the token manually.

Answer (score 0):

I also was experiencing the same issue. Then, I realized that Minecraft/Mojang accounts have security questions. If your function is getting the bearer token and your issue is that your access is denied when posting a name change request:

1st make sure your formatting it properly:
headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {TOKEN}"
*Notice the space between "Bearer" and {TOKEN}*

2nd: For some reason, Mojang needs you to send a Get request to their security challenges endpoint. *You don't have to do anything with the returned data..*
When you got the token manually, I'm assuming your browser automatically sent this get request and that's why it worked. If you're using proxies, you'll probably need to send a post request with your security question answers, look at the API link for documentation.

For Example:

```
res = requests.get(
            "https://api.mojang.com/user/security/challenges",
            headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {TOKEN}"},
        )
```

https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API
Go to the bottom under **"Security question-answer flow"**